# How to round a double to be a whole # while still keeping it a Double (wrapper class)?

Tags: java, double, rounding

I keep getting crazy decimals. For example, two of the numbers my code returned were 73.897886248014 and 46.102113751985996.

I simply need a method that returns 74.0 and 46.0. The data type needs to stay as a Double. I've tried several things, but I can't do it without changing the data type.

Answer (score 4):

Java has a function just for this: [`Math.rint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#rint-double-). It takes a double and rounds it to the nearest integer, but it returns a double instead of an int like `Math.round` does.

Comment: It is better to link to the official documentation, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#rint-double-

Comment: I had no idea that this was a method or that there was a common-enough need for it that it was part of the standard API.   Interesting, thank you.  This is a better solution than the one in the answer linked in the duplicate (for this specific case of 0 decimal places, mind).